# getting the offset of a record in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have some query on a table which can be sorted by any of several columns, and an id of a row in the resultset. How can I get the next or previous records (or the offset of the id in the complete resultset).

ie. 
let's say I have the following table

```
ID First_Col Second_Col Name
1   34        24         John
2   40        22         James
3   48        5          Hugh
```

If sorting by first_col, and given id 2, the next record would be 3, but if sorting by Second_Col, the next record would be 1.

Given the sortBy expression (which is passed to my function), and the id, how can I find the next record easily?

Comment: Are you trying to implement a pagination function?

Comment: not able to understand the issue? What you want to achieve here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
names
WHERE
Second_Col > (SELECT Second_Col FROM names WHERE ID = 2)
ORDER BY
Second_Col 
LIMIT 1
```

See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a84e9c/1

Answer (score 0):

Here you are: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8761/5

Probably it can be done more efficient but it works:

```
SELECT T.ID from TBL T WHERE 
T.SECOND_COL=
(SELECT MIN(TT.SECOND_COL) FROM TBL TT WHERE TT.SECOND_COL>(SELECT TTT.SECOND_COL FROM TBL TTT WHERE ID=2))
```

Comment: First, your example is using MS SQL Server, not MySQL, and you're right, it *can* be done more efficiently here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12131322/1432614

Comment: MS SQL? This is standard ANSI SQL. Where did you come up with this?